# Python XML 'TypeError: must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not str'

Tags: python, xml, csv, elementtree

I currently am trying to build an XML file from a CSV file. Currently my code reads the CSV file to data and begins creating the XML from the data that is stored within the CSV.

CSV Example:

```
Element,XMLFile
SubElement,XMLName,XMLFile
SubElement,XMLDate,XMLName
SubElement,XMLInformation,XMLDate
SubElement,XMLTime,XMLName
```

Expected Output:

```
<XMLFile>
    <XMLName>
        <XMLDate>
            <XMLInformation />
        </XMLDate>
        <XMLTime />
    </XMLName>
</XMLFile>
```

Currently my code attempts to look at the CSV to see what the parent is for the new subelement:

```
# Defines main element
# xmlElement = xml.Element(XMLFile)
xmlElement = xml.Element(csvData[rowNumber][columnNumber])

# Should Define desired parent (FAIL) and SubElement name (PASS)
# xmlSubElement = xml.SubElement(XMLFile, XMLName)
xmlSubElement = xml.SubElement(csvData[rowNumber][columnNumber + 2], csvData[rowNumber][columnNumber + 1])
```

When the code attempts to use the CSV source string as the parent parameter, Python 3.5 generates the following error:

```
TypeError: must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not str
```

Known cause of the error is that the parent paramenter is being returned as a string, when it is expected to be an Element or SubElement.

Is it possible to recall the stored value from the CSV and have it reference the Element or SubElement, instead of a string? The goal is to allow the code to read the CSV file and assign any SubElement to the parent listed in the CSV.

Comment: you're asking generally how do you look up elements by string. in general, you'll need to create your own lookup dictionary for it, and/or use xpath to search for it (less efficient, but less memory). alternately, if you just need the parent, if you use lxml, the parent is stored in the element (unlike the default ElementTree implementation). this has other side effects (if you do `e = Element(), e2 = Element(); s=SubElement(e, 's'); e2.append(s)`, in ElementTree both `e` and `e2` now have a copy, in lxml it gets moved from `e` to `e2`...) but it's sometimes useful...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell for sure, but it looks like you are doing:
ElementTree.SubElement(str, str)

when you should be doing:
ElementTree.SubElement(Element, str)

It also seems like you already know this. The real question, then, is how are you going to reference the parent object when you only know its tag string? You could search for Elements in the ElementTree with that particular tag string, but this is generally not a good idea as XML allows multiple instances of similar elements.

I would suggest you either:

- Find a strategy to store references to parent elements
- See if there is a way to uniquely identify the parent element using XPath